# ElasticsearchParseException

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I get this error

**ElasticsearchParseException[End of query source reached but query is not complete.]; }]**

I have absolutely no idea what it is mean

**Traceback**:

```
File "/home/Admin/.virtualenvs/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/Admin/.virtualenvs/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/Admin/.virtualenvs/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.50.0.39/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py" in wrapper
  827.             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/Admin/.virtualenvs/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/Admin/Projects/CMS/cms/catalogue/views.py" in get
  203.                     data = self.get_response(**kwargs)
File "/home/Admin/Projects/CMS/cms/catalogue/views.py" in get_response
  1782.         for asset, people in izip_longest(*response):
File "/home/Admin/.virtualenvs/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyes/es.py" in next
  1747.             self._do_search()
File "/home/Admin/.virtualenvs/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyes/es.py" in _do_search
  1575.             self._results = self._search_raw(self.start, self.chuck_size)
File "/home/Admin/.virtualenvs/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyes/es.py" in _search_raw
  1789.                                           doc_types=self.doc_types, **query_params)
File "/home/Admin/.virtualenvs/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyes/es.py" in search_raw
  1280.         return self._send_request('GET', path, body, params=query_params)
File "/home/Admin/.virtualenvs/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyes/es.py" in _send_request
  407.             raise_if_error(response.status, decoded)
File "/home/Admin/.virtualenvs/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyes/convert_errors.py" in raise_if_error
  93.     raise exceptions.ElasticSearchException(error, status, result, request)

Exception Type: ElasticSearchException at /catalogue/menu-search
Exception Value: ElasticsearchParseException[End of query source reached but query is not complete.]; }]
```

It seems the error occur when iterating on izip_longest :

```
    response = conn.search_multi([search_title, search_cast], indices_list=[es_alias] * 2,
                                 doc_types_list=['asset', 'people'] * 2)

    response._do_search()

    for asset, people in izip_longest(*response):
        ...
```

Any idea?

Comment: It means you made a mistake in your code

Comment: obviously, that's how I get an error, but where did I do that mistake and how to solve it?